# How can I get this to run?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop, stringbuilder

Seems like I've tried everything but nothing is working. How can I get this so the user can decide whether or not to add another name? I can run the for loop just fine without user decision.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Part2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int STUDENT_SIZE = 50;

        char choice1 = 'n';
        int i = 0;
        int stdntLength = 0;
        boolean choice = true;

        String[] stdntName = new String[STUDENT_SIZE];
        String[] WIDNUM = new String[STUDENT_SIZE];
        int[] EXM1 = new int[STUDENT_SIZE];
        int[] EXM2 = new int[STUDENT_SIZE];
        int[] EXM3 = new int[STUDENT_SIZE];
        int[] finalExm = new int[STUDENT_SIZE];

        do {
            for (i = 0; i < stdntName.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the name of Student "
                        + (i + 1) + ": ");
                stdntName[i] = s.nextLine();
                String fullName = stdntName[i];
                String str[] = fullName.split(" ");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(str[1]);
                sb.append(", ");
                sb.append(str[0]);
                String fullname = sb.toString();

                stdntName[i] = fullname;
                System.out.println(stdntName[i]);

                System.out.print("Do you wish to enter another? (y/n): ");
                choice1 = s.next().charAt(0);
            }
        } while (choice1 == 'y');
    }
}
```

Comment: HINT: Just asking the user whether he wants to stop or continue at the end of the `for` loop doesn't have the slightest effect on the `for` loop: it keeps going no matter what.  And the `do/while` loop surrounds the `for` loop, so it doesn't have any control until the `for` loop has completed.

Answer (score 0):

`do-while` loop seems to be redundant and may be removed.

Upon entering data of the i-th student, it's better to check the input for `y` and break if any character other than `y` is entered.

**Update**
Other issues that need to be addressed:

1. Check the length of the `str` upon splitting the full name; move *the last* name to the beginning (not just *the second* name).
2. Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` when reading `choice1` - because `\n` is not consumed and the next name read with `nextLine` will be an empty line.

```java
for (i=0; i < stdntName.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of Student " + (i+1) + ": ");
        stdntName[i] = s.nextLine();
        String fullName = stdntName[i];
        String str []  = fullName.split(" ");
        if (str.length > 1) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(str[str.length - 1]); // move the last name to beginning
            sb.append(", ");
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length - 1; j++) { // join remaining names
                if (j > 0) {
                    sb.append(' ');
                }
                sb.append(str[j]);
            }
            
            stdntName[i] = sb.toString();
        }
        System.out.println(stdntName[i]);
        
        System.out.print("Do you wish to enter another? (y/n): ");
        choice1 = s.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0); // read entire line
        if (choice1 != 'y') {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same error message for some reason

Comment: What is the error message and stack trace? Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: The error message is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
 at Part2.main(Part2.java:35)